# Convergence of an infinite series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am having trouble with the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac n {n+1}$$

I want to know if it converges or not, and I´ve tried with the comparision test, the ratio test, the Leibniz test...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let $a_n$ be a real valued sequence then we have the equivalence
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|a_n|=0$$

Here $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|(-1)^n\dfrac{n}{n+1}|\not = 0$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{n}{n+1}\not = 0$
hence the series $\sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n\dfrac{n}{n+1}$ can't be convergent. It is then a divergent series.

Answer (score 1):

Try the divergence test.  If the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}
$$
isn't $0$, then it diverges.

Comment: It may sound silly, but I was already doing it and I´m completely stuck with the limit. I mean, with $(-1)^n$, I just don´t know how to work with that, as $log(-1)$ does not exist. Am I making sense?

Comment: How did you get $log$ term in limit?

Comment: I replaced $(-1)^n=e^{nlog(-1)}$

Comment: You need to show that $(−1)^n$ does not converge. Argue by contradiction suppose that $(−1)^n\rightarrow L$. Then given $\varepsilon$, there is some $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $|(−1)^n−L|\le \varepsilon$. If $n$ is even so $|1−L|\le \varepsilon$, if $n$ is odd $|1+L|\le \varepsilon$. Then $2=|1+1|≤|1+L|+|1−L|\le 2\varepsilon$. Setting $ \varepsilon<1$, we have a contradiction. Then the limit doesn't exist as desired.

Comment: Got it, but even if $(−1)^n$ does not converge, that does not mean that $(-1)^n \frac n {n+1}$ doesn´t.

Comment: But I´ve realized now that I didn´t have to use log, taking the absolute value of the sequence was enough. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Yes the problem is that $n/(n+1) \not \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 1):

For series $\sum_{i=1}^{i=\infty}a_n$.if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$,then series diverges